# session variable is not passing to next page

Tags: php

index.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>


    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery- .min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 360px)" href="portrait.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 480px)" href="landscape.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)" href="desktop.css">


    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="banner">

  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</br></br></br>

    <br /><br /><br /><br />
<?php    echo $reg; ?>
<form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table border="2" align="center" width="400px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" style="border-color:#FFF;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background:#4CAF50; font-weight:bold;" colspan="2">लॉगिन</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>यूजर का नाम: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" size="25"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>पासवर्ड:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" size="25"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="Submit" value="submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2.login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
if($name=='admin' && $password=='admin')
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sid']=session_id();
header('location:template.php');
}
else
{
header('location:index.php');

$_SESSION['reg']="<font color=#800000; size=4>Invalid User Name and Password. Please Enter Again.</font>";
}
?>
```

3. template.php

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
   type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 360px)" href="portrait.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 480px)" href="landscape.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)" href="desktop.css">


   <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
   rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="container">

     <div id="navbar">
       <ul>
         <li align="center"><a href="template.php">मुख पृष्ठ </a></li>
      <li align="center"><a href="ftender.php">निविदा</a></li>
      <li align="center"><a href="workorderlogin.php">कार्य आदेश </a></li>
      <li align="center"><a href="salary.php">वेतन</a></li>
      <li align="center"><a href="shoprent.php">दुकान </a></li>
      <li align="center"><a href="stock.php">स्टॉक</a></li>
      <li align="center"><a href="misleneous.php">विविध</a></li>
        <li align="center"><a href="account.php">लेखा-जोखा</a></li>
     <li align="center"><a href="index.php">लोग आउट</a></li>
   </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>

     <div id="content">
     <br/><br/><br/><br/>
       <center><img  src=images/looks-solid.jpg width=500 height=250  alt=Edit /></center> 
        </br> </br><br/><br/>

       </div>

     <div id="bottom"></div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php }
     else
       {
           header("location:index.php");
       }
    ?>

   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. logout.php

   `session_start();
   session_destroy();
   setcookie(PHPSESSID,session_id(),time()-1);
   header('location:index.php');`


   ?>

My session is not working on online project, but on localhost,it is working correctly. I want after logout, on pressing back button it should not show the page,that it shows after login.

Comment: In template.php you have this: '<?php }
  else
    {
        header("location:index.php");
    }
 ?>' Where is the if statement before the else?

Comment: Exactly, and use `session_start()` once is enough. Now your using it twice in the login.php

Comment: what should i use instead session_id(), so that not to create new cookie again on session_start();

Comment: `index.php` - you're starting a session, but never read nor write anything in the session.
`login.php` - you start the session twice. why? you only need it once at the beginning of the file.
`template.php` - you use a header() function in the middle of the file. That will never work. The moment you already outputted content to the browser, you can't send headers anymore (please read the documentation)

Comment: No it's fine to use, please provide your if statement on template.php

Comment: <?php
 session_start();
 if($_SESSION['sid']==session_id())
 {
?>

Comment: should i not use else statement on template.php page